# Hitting the user rate limit on the google drive api with only 6 queries total

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

Currently using the google drive api with gdrive.Getting the error:

```
"Error: <HttpError 403 when requesting None returned "User rate limit exceeded". Details: "[{'message': 'User rate limit exceeded', 'domain': 'usageLimits', 'reason': 'userRateLimitExceeded', 'location': 'user', 'locationType': 'other'}]">
```

According to the quotas page, there were only 6 queries out of 12000 per minute

Relevant code(replace [Path to your client secret] and [google drive folder id] with your own) that will upload a file named image.jpg (user rate limit only happend with a shared drive):

```py
import time
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

def upload_file(drive_service, folder_id, filename):
    delay = 0  # start with no backoff

    while True:  # keep trying until the file is successfully uploaded
        try:
            time.sleep(delay)  # backoff

            # Create a file in the Drive with a numbered name
            file_metadata = {
                'name': filename,
                'parents': [folder_id]
            }
            media = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype='image/jpeg')
            file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()

            # If the upload was successful, break the loop
            break
        except Exception as e:
            if '403' in str(e):  # if rejected with a rate limit
                delay += 2  # add 2s to delay to guarantee the next attempt will be OK
            print(f"Error: {e}, retrying in {delay} seconds")

        if delay > 0:  # if we are currently backing off
            delay = max(0, delay - 0.2)  # reduce the backoff delay

def main():
    # Load the credentials from 'client_secret.json'
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        '[Path to your client secret json]',
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    )
    creds = flow.run_local_server(port=8080)

    # Build the Drive service
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Specify the ID of the folder in Google Drive where the images will be uploaded
    folder_id = '[Google Drive folder ID]'

    # Specify the filename of the image to be uploaded
    filename = 'image.jpg'

    # Upload the file
    upload_file(drive_service, folder_id, filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I added exponential back off and a delay using bottleneck.

I expected it to work with my test image, nothing was uploaded. At 350 ms between queries, that should be about 3 queries by second, which is way below the 10/sec described in [this] post.([How to Resolve a 403 error: User rate limit exceeded in Google Drive API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68483840/how-to-resolve-a-403-error-user-rate-limit-exceeded-in-google-drive-api)) post

EDIT: This rate limit problem only affects shared drive, trying it out on my personal drive worked flawlessly.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and Google Drive API. Can I ask you about the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: I've added a reproducible example to the post.